# Separate CSS Stylesheet for Desktop

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently creating a Bootstrap 3 website for mobile and desktop, taking the mobile first approach.

I have been following this webpage [Creating a Mobile-First Responsive Web Design](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/)

It mentions using a style.css for mobile view and enhanced.css stylesheet for a desktop view.

I know this is possibly quite basic but I am slightly confused as I am currently using one stylesheet which holds the mobile styles as default and I am using media queries for the tablet and desktop views.

I want to know what styles should be added into the enhanced.css stylesheet for desktop view?

Comment: Bootstrap handles all of that for you, in that article they are doing it from scratch.

Comment: Thank you for your comment so you are saying that I am doing the right thing by simply keeping everything in the same stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter whether or not you separate it into multiple stylesheets or one stylesheet. It really is a matter of personal preference.

I personally use one style sheet for things that I want to be universal throughout the entire website (such as a universal font, or a universal  font color). I call that sheet pageFormat.css.

Then I create a separate CSS file for each page I create if I plan on adding and adjusting things such as button sizes specific for that page.

Just be sure that whether you are including one stylesheet, or multiple, you are including the link reference so your HTML browser knows where to locate the CSS file that has all the data.